# Secondary OS Installation "PATH" environment variable pointing to Primary OS location

Tags: windows, installation, windows-server-2008, path, environment-variables

I recently installed a secondary OS Windows Server 2008 R2 std. edition on my PC which is having Windows7 Professorial edition as the primary OS.

Now the problem is, if I execute "PATH" command in windows server 2008 R2, it shows system32 and windows folder paths pointing to C:\ drive instead of G:\ drive. G: drive is the location where I had installed Win2008 OS.

I haven't changed any PATH setting nor installed any applications. When I looked in Disk Management it shows C:\ drive as the active partition.

My concern is, if edit the PATH environment variable to point to G:\ drive will that affect Win2008 OS?

Edit: The worst thing is, if I try to install applications like .NET framework, VS.NET or SQL server in Win2008, some of its components by default gets installed to C:\ drive instead of G:\ drive.

Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Are you sure C drive on Win2008R2 is not the G drive you are seeing under Win7? Because, I cannot imagine any Windows having its system partition on any other drive letter than C.

Comment: @Bora: Yes I did check this while troubleshooting on my own. Thanks for brining up that point.

Comment: @Bora: It's relatively uncommon, but in no way a miracle. In WinNT, drive letters have very little special meaning.

Comment: @AJP: I am trying to understand your question.  Are you saying that you have two different Windows OS installed on two different hard drives (or partitions) and are switching between them via dual-boot?